# Get client's request type using RACK middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rack

I have an api request say "host/something/abc.xml" which doesn't send content_type. Rails still understands that it needs to respond with xml and sends an xml data. If the same client calls with "host/something/abc" rails sends back an HTML. (Both doesn't have CONTENT_TYPE)

I wonder how it happens? I want to check in Rack middleware what the client is requesting? XML OR JSON OR HTML ( I do not have content type). Is there any method in Rack::Request to check it? I know there is a method content_type but it returns me nil. But still rails responds with xml.. How??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

`Content-Type` tells you type of the *request*. `Accept` tells the server what the client wants as a *response*.

This should output the accept header to the console.

```
require 'rack'

class Accepter
  def initialize(app, options={})
    @app, @options = app, options
  end
  def call(env)
    accepts = env["HTTP_ACCEPT"]
    warn "accepts = #{accepts.inspect}"
    @app.call
  end
end
```